# Cross domain communication

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am developing an iframe facebook app.

At some point, I open a facebook friends dialog on to which I have put a html button, so that I can add some logic specific to my app.

```
dialog = FB.ui({
                method:'fbml.dialog', 
                fbml: (
                    '<fb:request-form  target="_self" action="http://devel.home.net/facebook/?cmd=fb_submit_form" ' +
                        'method="post" invite="false" type="event" ' +
                        'content="Would you like to attend the '+fb.EVENT.displayName+' event? &lt;fb:req-choice url=\'http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid='+fb.EVENT.details.fb_event.id+'\' label=\'Respond now\' /&gt;" >' + 
                        emails.join('') +
                        '<input type="hidden" fb_protected="true" name="event" value="'+fb.RESPONSE.id+'"/>' +
                        '<fb:multi-friend-selector email_invite="false" import_external_friends="false" exclude_ids="'+appUsers+'"'+
                            'condensed="true" showborder="false" bypass="cancel" actiontext="Invite your friends to join" /> '+

                        '<br/><fb:request-form-submit import_external_friends="false"/>' +
                    '</fb:request-form>' + 

                    '<div style="padding:10px">You are also sending '+fb.EMAILS.length+' invitations via email</div>' + 
                    '<button id="email-button">Send Emails</button>'
                    ),
                    size: { width:640, height:480}, width:640, height:480
                });


            $('.fb_dialog_iframe').find('IFRAME').load(function(){
                $(this).contents().find('#email-button').click(function(){
                    alert(1)
                });
            })
```

Basically, Facebook creates an iframe for the dialog

So I attach an onload handler to the iframe and I try to access the button

At that I get the permission denied error

```
Permission denied for <http://devel.home.net> (document.domain=<http://home.net>) to get property HTMLDocument.ownerDocument from <https://www.facebook.com> (document.domain=<https://facebook.com>).
```

Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform Cross-site scripting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) particularly to a network such as Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Only possible way is using either a flash or a silverlight object.